# storm KafkaSpout stopped to consume message from kafka (NOT_LEADER_FOR_PARTITION)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I have three zookeeper and three kafka and storm in cluster enviroinment

storm nimbus is working on machine1 and storm supervisor working on machine 2 and 3

at some point KafkaSpout stopped consuming data from kafka and i found error

```
2016-11-16 04:02:07.470 c.e.m.s.k.KafkaSpout [WARN] Fetch failed
com.monitor.storm.kafka.FailedFetchException: Error fetching data from [Partition{host=<machine1_ip>:9092, partition=1}] for topic [test_topic]: [NOT_LEADER_FOR_PARTITION]
    at com.monitor.storm.kafka.KafkaUtils.fetchMessages(KafkaUtils.java:193) ~[storm-kafka-0.8-plus.jar:newtrunk.10.25.2016]
    at com.monitor.storm.kafka.PartitionManager.fill(PartitionManager.java:175) ~[storm-kafka-0.8-plus.jar:newtrunk.10.25.2016]
    at com.monitor.storm.kafka.PartitionManager.next(PartitionManager.java:132) ~[storm-kafka-0.8-plus.jar:newtrunk.10.25.2016]
    at com.monitor.storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.nextTuple(KafkaSpout.java:153) [storm-kafka-0.8-plus.jar:newtrunk.10.25.2016]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__5624$fn__5639$fn__5670.invoke(executor.clj:607) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__545.invoke(util.clj:479) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_73]
2016-11-16 04:02:07.471 c.e.m.s.k.ZkCoordinator [INFO] Task [2/4] Refreshing partition manager connections
```

- I have checked all the services were up and running fine.
- I have tried telnet all the ports are reachable.
- If i delete all the topic and restart the services(zookeeper, kafka , storm (nimbus, supervisor, workers) ) it will work fine.
  But, i can't deleted topics. Because, it has some data in it.And after few hours it seem started to working fine without restart.But, it started to happen frequently. So, their is some delay in actions.
- Can any one help me to find out what is the problem and is the their
  any way i can prevent it.

Comment: Do you find any leader for the `partition 1 of test_topic` using the console commands? If the leader fails then automatically leader election polling will be taken and a new leader will be available for the partition. It is kakfa behavior.

Comment: have you finished this concept. now am doing this same concept .

Comment: I suspected this issue occurred due to zookeeper performance issue. So, I have tuned the zookeeper by configuring 'dataDir' and 'dataLogDir' to separate drive for high throughput. After that I never faced this issue again